# Who can explain the new options of chdsk on Windows 8/10?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, windows-10, cmd.exe, chkdsk

Who can explain the new options of chdsk on Windows 8/10 ?
 The new options are

```
1./scan 
2./forceofflinefix
3./perf
4./spotfix
5./sdcleanup
6./offlinescanandfix
7./freeorphanedchains
8./markclean
```

I cannot find any explanation except the chkdsk /? informations but there is few informations and the source : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/b8/2012/05/09/redesigning-chkdsk-and-the-new-ntfs-health-model/ does not explain the /sdcleanup neither the difference between /offlinescanandfix and /forceofflinefix and /r

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts (this one and http://superuser.com/users/595020/christophe-maggi). See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's stance on the changes to chkdsk

> So in Windows 8, we’ve changed the way we approach the health model of
>   NTFS and changed the way we fix corruptions so as to minimize the
>   downtime due to chkdsk. We’ve also introduced a new file system for
>   the future, ReFS, which does not require an offline chkdsk to repair
>   corruptions.

Source: [Redesigning chkdsk and the new NTFS health model](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/b8/2012/05/09/redesigning-chkdsk-and-the-new-ntfs-health-model/)

### NTFS-only switches

> 1. /scan  Runs an online scan on the specified partition.
> 2. /forceofflinefix   Bypass all online repair; all defects found are queued for offline repair (i.e. chkdsk /spotfix). Should not be used
>      without "/scan".
> 3. /perf  Uses more system resources to complete a scan as fast as possible. This may have a negative performance impact on other tasks
>      running on the system.
> 4. /spotfix   Runs spot fixing on the specified volume.
> 5. /sdcleanup Garbage collect unneeded security descriptor data. Must be used with "/F".
> 6. /offlinescanandfix Runs an offline scan on the specified volume and fixes errors if any corruption is detected.

### FAT/FAT32/exFAT-only switches

> 1. /freeorphanedchains    Frees any orphaned cluster chains instead of recovering their contents.
> 2. /markclean Marks the volume clean if no corruption was detected, even if "/F" was not set.

Source: [Check disk in Windows 10](http://www.tenuser.com/config/disk/chkdsk.htm)